# Buttons and Entry Label not appearing where they should actually appear

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

If i'm removing the entry widget, everything adjusts perfectly, but after adding the entry widget, everything gets scrambled. I'm using grid geometry manager and i've specified the location of the entry box, but still it isn't displaying correctly.

```
from Tkinter import*
root=Tk()
root.title("Calculator")
def calculate():
    print x
def callback(x):
    print x
Entry(root).grid(row=0)
Button(root,text="0",command=lambda:callback(0)).grid(row=4,column=1)
Button(root,text="1",command=lambda:callback(1)).grid(row=1,column=0)
Button(root,text="2",command=lambda:callback(2)).grid(row=1,column=1)
Button(root,text="3",command=lambda:callback(3)).grid(row=1,column=2)
Button(root,text="4",command=lambda:callback(4)).grid(row=2,column=0)
Button(root,text="5",command=lambda:callback(5)).grid(row=2,column=1)
Button(root,text="6",command=lambda:callback(6)).grid(row=2,column=2)
Button(root,text="7",command=lambda:callback(7)).grid(row=3,column=0)
Button(root,text="8",command=lambda:callback(8)).grid(row=3,column=1)
Button(root,text="9",command=lambda:callback(9)).grid(row=3,column=2)
Button(root,text="+",command=lambda:callback(12)).grid(row=1,column=3)
Button(root,text="-",command=lambda:callback(13)).grid(row=2,column=3)
Button(root,text="*",command=lambda:callback(14)).grid(row=3,column=3)
Button(root,text="/",command=lambda:callback(15)).grid(row=4,column=3)
Button(root,text="=",command=calculate).grid(row=4,column=2)
Button(root,text=".",command=lambda:callback(11)).grid(row=4,column=0)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: when you put `entry` then all cells in the same column get the same width. Use `columnspan` so Entry uses more columns - ie. `Entry(root).grid(row=0, columnspan=4)`. Or use `Frame` and `pack` to organize elemnents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is grid - when you add `Entry` in column then other cells in the same column have the same width. You can use columnspan to use more columns for `Entry`

```
tk.Entry(root).grid(row=0, columnspan=4)
```

And you can use `sticky='we'` to resize buttons to cell width.

```
import Tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def calculate():
    print x

def callback(x):
    print x

# --- main ---

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Calculator")

tk.Entry(root).grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

tk.Button(root, text="0", command=lambda:callback(0)).grid(row=4, column=1, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text="1", command=lambda:callback(1)).grid(row=1, column=0, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text="2", command=lambda:callback(2)).grid(row=1, column=1, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text="3", command=lambda:callback(3)).grid(row=1, column=2, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text="4", command=lambda:callback(4)).grid(row=2, column=0, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text="5", command=lambda:callback(5)).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text="6", command=lambda:callback(6)).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text="7", command=lambda:callback(7)).grid(row=3, column=0, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text="8", command=lambda:callback(8)).grid(row=3, column=1, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text="9", command=lambda:callback(9)).grid(row=3, column=2, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text="+", command=lambda:callback(12)).grid(row=1, column=3, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text="-", command=lambda:callback(13)).grid(row=2, column=3, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text="*", command=lambda:callback(14)).grid(row=3, column=3, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text="/", command=lambda:callback(15)).grid(row=4, column=3, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text="=", command=calculate).grid(row=4, column=2, sticky='we')
tk.Button(root, text=".", command=lambda:callback(11)).grid(row=4, column=0, sticky='we')

root.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** shorter

```
import Tkinter as tk

# --- functions ---

def callback(x):
    print x

# --- main ---

buttons = [
  ("1", "2", "3", "+"),
  ("4", "5", "6", "-"),
  ("7", "8", "9", "*"),
  (".", "0", "=", "/"),
]

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Calculator")

tk.Entry(root).grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

for r, row in enumerate(buttons, 1):
    for c, text in enumerate(row):
        b = tk.Button(root, text=text, command=lambda arg=text:callback(arg))
        b.grid(row=r, column=c, sticky='we')

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Will you please explain me these two lines?

for r, row in enumerate(buttons, 1):
    for c, text in enumerate(row):

Comment: Thanks for the help, i figured it out myself! :)